# prime counting function pi bounds

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

is it true that for some integer $n_0$, that all integer numbers n such that $n \geq n_0$ the following holds true for the prime counting function :

$\frac{x}{\ln x} (1+\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{2}{\ln^2 x}+\frac{6}{\ln^3 x}+\frac{24}{\ln^4 x}) \leq \pi(x) \leq \frac{x}{\ln x} (1+\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{2}{\ln^2 x}+\frac{6}{\ln^3 x}+\frac{30}{\ln^4 x})$

also is this the general case : $\pi(x) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i!}{\ln^i x}$

Comment: For the latter question: this is not in general true. Indeed, this is never true - the sum doesn't converge for any $x$.

Comment: It is true in the sense of asymptotic series though.

Comment: It is true that $x/\ln(x)(1+1/(2 \ln(x))\le \pi(x)$ for $59\le x$ and $\pi(x)\le x/\ln(x)(1+3/(2\ln(x))$ for $1\le x$.  These and more precise results can be found in the old work of Rosser and Schoenfeld.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your series diverges rapidly.  It's true that $\mathrm{Li}(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}$ has an asymptotic expansion of the form you suggest (and which can be derived by integrating by parts), but this means that in the limit $x\to\infty$ you can approximate $\mathrm{Li}(x)$  by finite sums, not that the series converges.

Editing to add: For your precise question, the PNT for $\pi(x)$ has the same error term as the more familiar PNT for $\psi(x)$: $\pi(x) = \mathrm{Li}(x) + O\left(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)$.  Since $e^{c\sqrt{\log x}}$ grows faster than any power of the logarithm, this error term will be smaller than the error terms in the asymptotic expansion for $\mathrm{Li}(x)$.

Comment: Of course it is. The error term is (considerably) smaller than $x/(\log x)^k$ for any constant $k$, hence the asymptotic expansion for Li is valid for $\pi(x)$ just the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I'll do the exercise.